# Xamarin.Android Dynamic Shared Library ABIs missing (System.DllNotFoundException)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk, xamarin.android

I'm currently developing an Android app that uses an existing C library. It's a Xamarin.Android app.
I added a Dynamic Shared Library (Android) project to the solution and referenced it from the main Android project. But I cannot figure out how to get the app working with the native library.

I always get the following exception (System.DllNotFoundException) when I try to invoke a native function:

```
12-09 17:24:36.390 E/mono-rt ( 3833): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: mynativelib
```

When I debug the application I can see that there is a `libmynativelib.so` in the `armeabi-v7a` folder under `libs` in the `.apk`. I build the app for `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, and `x86`.

The log shows the following line:

```
12-09 17:24:29.881 D/Mono    ( 3833): DllImport error loading library './libmynativelib': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.meiglets.myapp-1/lib/arm/./libmynativelib" not found
```

I assumed that the device is going to lookup the library in a folder like `arm-v7a` or similar. Futhermore, I thought that Visual Studio builds the native library for each platform and puts it in the according directory under `libs`. But that's not the case.

I'm running/debugging the app on a Motorola Moto G2 XT1068 (Android 6.0 - API 23).

Some information about the IDE and versions:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

  - Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Microsoft .NET Framework

  - Version 4.6.01586
- Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)

  - 14.0.25401.00
- Xamarin

  - 4.2.1.64 (872717c)
- Xamarin.Android

  - 7.0.2.37 (ce955cc)

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me figure out how to get the app running.

Comment: Add your three `.so` libs to the `Xamarin.Android` project, each with their own ABI directory (`lib/{ABI}/nameOfLib.so`) and set the build type of `AndroidNativeLibrary` (or `EmbeddedNativeLibrary` if this is a library project), then `path sniffing` will find the correct `.so` to load.

Comment: it's a library project I'd also like to debug, thus it is referenced from the Xamarin.Android project. Anyway, I still couldn't figure out how I can build the native library for each ABI

Comment: You do know that `armeabi-v7a` libs won't be loaded on non-armv7  `armeabi` and `x86` devices, right? Thats probably the root cause of your invalid abi error.

Comment: yes I know that. the Motorola Moto G2 is a `armeabi-v7a,armeabi` device, and there is a `armeabi-v7a` directory with the `libmynativelib.so`, but still I get the `DLLNotFoundExecption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one `.so` file of the supported architecture will be installed. Thus it's either all-included or none included. You shouldn't mix this or else you'll have plenty of issues like the one you're running into.

One common mistake is not having `ABI`s for all and rather just the one you have a device for. I've even see people who only provide `armeabi` libs and no others. To get a proper ordered list of ABIs supported on your device, use `Build.SupportedAbis`:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.OS.Build.SupportedAbis/

Secondly, make sure the lib makes it to device by installing a helper app like `Native Libs Monitor`:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app

If the library does not make it to device, then you need to ensure the proper `Build Action` is set on the `.so` file.

> To deploy a native library with a Xamarin.Android library project, add the library binary to the project and set its Build Action to EmbeddedNativeLibrary.

**Source:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

Comment: I've accepted this answer, although it wasn't exactly the problem! I use `libgmp` in my native library project and forgot to add the pre-built `libgmp` files to the android project under `lib/{ABI}/libgmp.so`. Anyway, this answer draw my attention to this problem